# Make adds unexpected mv command

Tags: makefile, bison, flex-lexer

I'm using a makefile to build my flex/bison project. I'm having problems as it is adding a call to `yacc` and a `mv` command thus overwriting one of my files.

```
user@dk ~/calc ±master⚡ » make clean                                                                  
rm -rf lex.yy.c calc.tab.h calc.tab.c calc
user@dk ~/calc ±master » make
bison -d calc.y
flex calc.lex
g++ -o calc calc.tab.c lex.yy.c calc.c
user@dk ~/calc ±master⚡ » make clean
rm -rf lex.yy.c calc.tab.h calc.tab.c calc
user@dk ~/calc ±master » touch calc.y
user@dk ~/calc ±master » make
bison -d calc.y
flex calc.lex
yacc  calc.y
mv -f y.tab.c calc.c
g++ -o calc calc.tab.c lex.yy.c calc.c
... Failure ...
```

I simplified the makefile to the bare minimum to reproduce this. Using bison to create two files: `calc.tab.c` and `calc.tab.h`. I do not have the .h file as a target as I'm not sure what the correct way to do that is. The call to bison will generate both of the calc.tab.* files so that is not my main concern.

What is the correct way to structure this makefile to avoid the calls to yacc and mv from being generated?

```
calc: calc.tab.c lex.yy.c calc.c
    g++ -o calc calc.tab.c lex.yy.c calc.c

calc.tab.c: calc.y
    bison -d calc.y

lex.yy.c: calc.lex calc.tab.h
    flex calc.lex

clean:
    rm -rf lex.yy.c calc.tab.h calc.tab.c calc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mv` comes from `make`'s built-in rules, which contain:

```
%.c : %.y
    $(YACC.y) $<
    mv -f y.tab.c $@
```

It looks like `make` is trying to create `calc.c` from `calc.y`. Some solutions to this are to redefine that rule yourself, or rename `calc.y` to something that won't trigger that rule for `calc.c`, or disable `make`'s built-in rules.

You can list all built-in rules with `make -p`.

Comment: Makes sense. I didn't know about the implicit rules. Thank You.